# Java program latency issue

Tags: java, logging, log4j, execution, latency

I am comparing Java program latency by creating log using log4j and simple file read write

```
     String content = "Writing";

    File file = new File("D://filename.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


    long startTimeF=System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   
    {
        bw.write(content);

    }
    bw.close();
    long endTimeF=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time elapsed for file write:"+(endTimeF-startTimeF));
    long startTimeL=System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   
    {
        _logger.info("Writing..:"+strDate); }
    long endTimeL=System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Time elapsed for logger    ="+(endTimeL-startTimeL));
```

o/p:
Time elapsed for file write:1826647
Time elapsed for logger    =3909112

And suppose I interchange my lines likes

long startTimeL=System.nanoTime();

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   
    {
        _logger.info("writing..:"+strDate); }
    long endTimeL=System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Time elapsed for logger    ="+(endTimeL-startTimeL));

    long startTimeF=System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   
    {
        bw.write(content);

    }
    bw.close();
    long endTimeF=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time elapsed for file write:"+(endTimeF-startTimeF));
```

o/p:
Time elapsed for logger    =4018071
Time elapsed for file write:3115210

```
 What cause to get different output by only inter changing lines....(using Asynchronous Logging) ?
```

Comment: If you wish to benchmark the speed of different operations in a JVM do not just run them once as various additional time consuming tasks that the JVM does during initial startup may affect the results. Run your code in a loop and then average the time of each operation. If there is still a disparity between switching the position of the two logging methods then state that.

Comment: You should use some acceptable amount of work to perform a benchmark. If a block of code takes 3 or 4 milliseconds is not something that you should seriously be concerned about.

Comment: Query is why my log4j logger showing large latency time if executed after writing file code means

Comment: JVM takes some time to initialize. When you run a benchmark that is too short, the results would not be accurate. In this scenario Log4j needs some time to initialize itself too. Its loggers are loaded dynamically on runtime. If you write a larger benchmark so the initialization time is small compared to the task are measuring, I would expect similar performance when writing to a file